# Why only two modes of energy exchange?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

In the  *thermodynamics* chapter of the 11th standard, I read something that I have a hard time believing to be true:

"There are two ways by which a system can interact or exchange energy with its surroundings:
(i) Heat (ii) Work."

This is what I found in various books, exactly quoted from one of them.
Why only two? Why aren't there more ways for a system to interact or exchange energy with its surroundings? If there are, what are they?

Comment: Let's look from a different angle: **you** tell us what other ways there might be. If you won't name any, then at least you'll see why only two.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Well, these are forms of energy being used as 'modes of energy exchange'. Right? So, what if we try and use other forms of energy as modes of energy exchange?

Comment: Indeed, the system may exchange energy with its surroundings via light, or electric current, or by gravitation waves, or by whatever else. I guess all these subtleties are just omitted for clarity. Anyway, entry-level thermodynamics is mostly about gases in cylinders with pistons.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Okay. So other modes of "energy *exchange* " are possible?

Comment: It is a matter of convention, really. Maybe the authors of your book classify all these as merely forms of heat and work.

Comment: @IvanNeretin OK. Then, I mean, can you please give an example where light, for example is being used as a mode of energy exchange.

Comment: Think of the Sun as a thermodynamic system, and ourselves as a part of its surroundings.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Oh. Yes!

Comment: @IvanNeretin but radiation is a form of transfer of heat.

Comment: Yeah, sure. And gravitation waves are a form of work. A matter of convention, like I said.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So, technically, every exchange thing's heat and work!?

Comment: This is a matter of convention, how many times do I have to stress that? If your definition of heat includes light, fine. If it does not, that's OK anyway.

Comment: Oh.Ok. I got it now. Sorry for the inconvenience. And, thanks a lot! (: